# How to resolve WCF CommunicationException was unhandled

Tags: wcf, wshttpbinding, communicationexception

I have some problems.

the issue is `CommunicationException` error.

error message is

> An error occurred while receiving the
>   HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:18080/WCFServices/TestService.
>   This could be due to the service
>   endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an
>   HTTP request context being aborted by
>   the server (possibly due to the
>   service shutting down). See server
>   logs for more details.

I wrote below source code.

```
TestServiceClient client = new TestServiceClient();
TestSettings[] voltages = client.GetTestSettings();
```

Error message appears above tilt word.

I want to synchronize Main Application and Client Application.

Above error is Client Application.

My app.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITestService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:18080/WCFServices/TestService"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITestService"
        contract="TestServiceReference.ITestService"
        name="WSHttpBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

ps. TestService is modified that is temporarily

please anyone.

thanks.

oh sorry, error occurred on "voltage"

I tried to increase maxsize and length.

but, it didn`t resolve this issue.

somebody help me.

Comment: Show us your server config file, please.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your server side config it's going to be hard to help you troubleshoot.

Having said that, one of the things you can do to get the real underlying exception (you're not seeing what's really going on) is to [configure WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). Just drop that config snippet in the config file on your server side, and look through the logs generated. That should point you to the real problem. Make sure to take it back out when you're finished.